Monthly Average Precipitation
How reliable an indicator of drought are the monthly precipitation average stats that are on weather.com?  As population grows, is receiving the monthly average sufficient to meeting the water demands of the population or is more precipitation needed?

That depends on the definition of drought (and how accurate is weather.cm data).
As far as I know, in most countries drought definitions are relative. ie. 80% of the annual mean or absolute (ie. 400mm/year). this way drought has no relation to human demand of water.
